# What is the function of the Zener diode in this BMS schematic?

Tags: batteries, bms, cell-balancing

I am drawing the schematic of a battery management system (BMS) based on the [BQ76920](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76920.pdf?ts=1678426793611&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ76920). The application circuit in the datasheet shows the MOSFETs for balancing the voltage of each cell:

[image]

I compared it with a [github project](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS/blob/master/Schematic_01.png) with the same circuit. It uses a Zener diode in paralel to the MOSFET.

What is the purpose of using a Zener diode in this? I have read that Zener diodes conduct energy in reverse polarity instead of rectifier diodes.

Could somebody explain me the operation of the circuit please? How do the MOSFETs perform the balancing process?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What is the function of the Zener diode in this BMS schematic?*

[image]

The Zener diode limits the peak gate-to-source voltage to around 15 volts typically and, protects the MOSFET's gate-source region from over-voltages. In your particular circuit, a 16 volt Zener diode is used ([MMSZ5246B](https://docs.rs-online.com/2a8c/0900766b81321cf1.pdf)).

> *I have read that Zener diodes conduct energy in reverse polarity
> instead of rectifier diodes.*

They conduct current when the "Zener" voltage is exceeded and act as a "shunt" voltage regulator.

Comment: OP says "Zener in parallel to the MOSFET", not "in parallel to the MOSFET gate-source".

Comment: A MOSFET has three terminals and can only be made to be in parallel with another 3 terminal device so, I used my imagination LOL @RohatKılıç

Comment: @RohatKılıç It also does not specifically say in parallel to the MOSFET drain-source either, it just asks what the Zener does in the circuit.

Comment: @Justme true but when we say "parallel to the MOSFET" 99.9% of us will think "parallel to the MOSFET drain-source". And, again, it should have been quoted with its designator (D5). Because there are lots of Zener symbols "in parallel with MOSFETs" in the circuit.

Comment: Thank you Andy for your detailed explanation, now it is really clear for me!
And excuse me Rohat for not beeing explicit